# How can I download a MySQL's BLOB using Servlets and AJAX?

Tags: mysql, ajax, servlets, blob

I'm using a servlet to access the MySQL data. I already have the code for sending the file from the servlet to the response.

What I don't know is how I'm supossed to catch it with javascript, because I'm not making this call by submit. I don't want to reload the hole page.

I tried making a window.open to the servlet, sending all the params by URL, but it only opens a blank page.

Comment: Could you post your javascript code so that I can see where your error might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to download the file, I just query the blob file and then:

```
try{
    ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    stmt = (Statement) c.createStatement();
  rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  if (rs.next()) {
    fl = (Blob) rs.getBlob(1);
  } else {
      System.out.println("No se pudo descargar el archivo");
  }

  InputStream in = fl.getBinaryStream();
  int length = (int) fl.length();

    response.reset();
    //response.setContentType("multipart/mixed");
    //if(rs.getString(3).toLowerCase().equals("mp3") || rs.getString(3).toLowerCase().equals("mpeg"))
        response.setContentType(getMime(rs.getString(2)));
    response.setHeader("Content-Length: ",Integer.toString(length));
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=" + rs.getString(2));

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

while ((length = in.read(buf)) > 0){
    output.write(buf, 0, length);
}
    output.close();
    in.close();
    rs.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```